# What is this sounds? Car won't start

Tags: honda, battery, noise, crv

I've been having trouble with this car and keeping the battery charged. It's winter and the car doesn't get driven, lately I've decided to run it a bit every night. Tonight my wife tried to start it and it didn't so I was going to jump it. I come outside to this sound (no key in the ignition). Auto zone confirmed that the battery itself was fine and even charged it for me last week.

It only stops when I put the key in and turn it to on.
Honda crv

https://photos.app.goo.gl/K2P5QgVSdD4kp8XN6

Comment: "Running it a bit every night" won't help unless "a bit" is fifteen or twenty minutes' driving.  Any shorter run time won't recharge the battery from that evening's starts, and you'll end up discharging it sooner.

Answer (score 1):

I can't hear the noise in the video, but if it sounds like a power hand drill then the starter is spinning but the solenoid did not push the Bendix out into the flywheel/flexplate, check ignition or stuck relay / short in starter wiring. If it sounds like a clicking noise it could be the solenoid trying to push the Bendix out, or the relays chattering if it is coming from the relay box. Check for same as above.

Because you have been having trouble keeping it charged, I would remove the ignition start wire from the starter and check for voltage between it and ground while hooked to a fresh battery or high power wall car charger. If no voltage, go through the motions of starting with key and recheck. If there is voltage with the key out/off then it is most likely an ignition issue/short. If NO voltage is found have the starter checked. A sticky solenoid/non-disengaging ignition/short can cause this issue, but this is generally harder to do, so generally, I would check this last unless the first test shows voltage.